# How to add CarrierWave uploader to Devise registration view? (rails gems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, devise, carrierwave

When users register, I want them to be able to upload an avatar.  The new registration .html.erb looks like this:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:multipart => true} ) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div>
<%= f.label :username %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div>
<%= f.label :image %><br />
<%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>

<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

<div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "links" %>
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

ImageUploader exists...

When I try to visit the view, it tells me that User::ImageUploader doesn't exist.  When I try to specify the fully qualified name of the class in the user model, either as an 'include' statement or as an argument to the mount_uploader function, it can't find that either.  Do I need to somehow build in a separate form_tag in that view?  I'm sure this has been done before.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you:

1. Added an `:image` column to your User model?
2. Defined the uploader `app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb`?
3. Restarted your server?

You shouldn't need to have this as a separate form tag, as long as the image attribute exists on the User model.

You may need to check your form markup. I notice you have `:username` on the label and `:name` on the field.

Try changing:

```
<%= f.label :username %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

to

```
<%= f.label :name, "username" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

Comment: Yep, the User has an image in it, although I can't pull one up in the rails console without commenting out the reference to the ImageUploader (NameError: uninitialized constant User::ImageUploader , same thing I'm getting from the view.)  Restarting the server has no effect.  I'm going to edit the question to show what happens when ImageUploader is commented out of user.rb.

Comment: is the column on your User model called `name` or `username`? You have a label for one, and a field for the other in your form markup.

Comment: the column is called name, with the form label as 'username', and it seemed to work fine before this image stuff came along

Comment: `<%= f.label :name, "username" %>` might be better. Not sure if it will fix your problem though. Can you post your image_uploader.rb?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `When I try to specify the fully qualified name of the class in the user model`. Where are you storing the image url? As an attribute in the User model, or in a seperate model?

Comment: Weird!  That worked! (@ the :name, "username" comment).  Thank you so much.  You might want to edit your answer to include what fixed it, seeing as how I've upvoted and accepted it and it's not in there.